# Using Symbol MC70 series scanner with native code

Tags: windows-mobile, barcode, motorola

Is it possible to use Symbol MC70 series scanner with native code? I have a Windows Mobile application written using Lazarus(Object pascal) and I want to use it with Symbol MC70.

The sdk that they have are for C, .NET and Java. I had a look at the C sdk and it comes with .LIB files which I cannot use with Object Pascal. I have no clue as to how the scanner is working with .NET stuff, I could not see a WIN32 dll in the files provided, maybe it is in the cab file.

Any suggestions as to what I should do to get the scanners to work for me.

Sandeep

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/SymScan

Answer (score 0):

.lib files are for VS. Probably you need similar stuff, but then for GCC, the C compiler FPC is compatible with. These are ".a" files.

Trying to access .NET assemblies using COM is something that could be a workaround on normal Windows, don't know if it works with CE.